# Help with Silverlight and SharePoint

Tags: development, client-object-model, silverlight

As a continuation of my last question, I can get the data correctly now just I am having a problem getting it to display. I want it to be in a DataForm control but I seem to be unable to connect it correctly. here is my code:

```
namespace SP2010
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {

        ClientContext context;
        Web spWeb;
        List customerList;
        ListItemCollection allCustomers;
    public MainPage()
    {
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
            InitializeComponent();
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = this;
        context = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url);
        spWeb = context.Web;
        context.Load(spWeb);
        customerList = spWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("testlist");
        context.Load(customerList);
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml =
            @"<View>
            <Query></Query>
           <RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>
         </View>";
        allCustomers = customerList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        context.Load(allCustomers);
        context.ExecuteQueryAsync(new ClientRequestSucceededEventHandler(OnRequestSucceeded), new ClientRequestFailedEventHandler(OnRequestFailed));

    }
    private void OnRequestSucceeded(Object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DisplayListData);
    }
    private void OnRequestFailed(Object sender, ClientRequestFailedEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(args.ErrorDetails + "   " + args.Message);
    }
    public ObservableCollection<SPCustomers> Printers
    {
        get
        {
            if (printers == null)
            {
                printers = new ObservableCollection<SPCustomers>();
                foreach (ListItem item in allCustomers)
                {
                    printers.Add(new SPCustomers
                    {
                        IPAddress = item["Title"].ToString(),
                        Make = item["make"].ToString(),
                        Model = item["model"].ToString(),
                        xCord = item["x"].ToString(),
                        yCord = item["y"].ToString()
                    });
                }
            }
            return (printers);
         }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<SPCustomers> printers;
```

does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can we see the DisplayListData method?

Comment: for now it is empty because that was left over from a previous method I attempted  `<df:DataForm ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}" Height="276" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="dataForm1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376" />` is where I bind it to the dataform

Comment: The DisplayListData method will do the logic once the data has been returned form the server. If it's empty, nothing will happen.

Comment: Then how would I tell it to update or otherwise show the data that it is connected to?

Comment: The DisplayListData method would contain the logic to bind the data in your allCustomers (I think you can call 'GetDataTable' on this object, might need to 'Load' it first, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - real old post.. I kind of stumbled upon it...

- In your `MainPage_Loaded`-Method you set the `DataContext`. Ater that your UI will bind to `Printers`.
- This will cause the `Printers_get` to be executed - which in turn will iterate over `allCustomers`. `allCustomers` is either `null` or empty because `context.ExecuteQueryAsync(...)` will most definitively not have run at this point.
- Then - some time later - you call `context.ExecuteQueryAsync(...)` which fills `allCustomers` - but you never tell your UI that it is time to refresh the Printes...

Real quick (but IMHO the wrong way) would be to move your `this.DataContext = this` into `OnRequestSucceeded`.

I would:

- make MainPage implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`
- in `OnRequestSucceeded` raise the `PropertyChanged`-event with `Printers` as the argument and by doing so tell the UI that it is time to update the `Printers` binding.
- this will refresh the binding and re-execute `Printers_get` - which will do nothing new, because `printers` is no longer `null` - so I'd do something about that, too...

To stay close to your code a working example ("probably working" - I have not tested it..) would most probably look like this:

```
namespace SP2010
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {

        ClientContext context;
        Web spWeb;
        List customerList;
        ListItemCollection allCustomers;
    public MainPage()
    {
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Printers = new ObservableCollection<SPCustomers> ();
            this.DataContext = this;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        context = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url);
        spWeb = context.Web;
        context.Load(spWeb);
        customerList = spWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("testlist");
        context.Load(customerList);
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml =
            @"<View>
            <Query></Query>
           <RowLimit>1000</RowLimit>
         </View>";
        allCustomers = customerList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        context.Load(allCustomers);
        context.ExecuteQueryAsync(new ClientRequestSucceededEventHandler(OnRequestSucceeded), new ClientRequestFailedEventHandler(OnRequestFailed));

    }
    private void OnRequestSucceeded(Object sender, ClientRequestSucceededEventArgs args)
    {
        //Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DisplayListData);
        // Fill Printers:

        foreach (ListItem item in allCustomers)
        {
            Printers.Add(new SPCustomers
            {
                IPAddress = item["Title"].ToString(),
                Make = item["make"].ToString(),
                Model = item["model"].ToString(),
                xCord = item["x"].ToString(),
                yCord = item["y"].ToString()
            });
        }
    }
    private void OnRequestFailed(Object sender, ClientRequestFailedEventArgs args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(args.ErrorDetails + "   " + args.Message);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SPCustomers> Printers
    {
        get; private set;
    }
```

Notice that this still doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but `Printers` gets initialized in the contstructor and before setting the DataContext. This way the Binding to Printers will be o.k. and as you already utilized an `ObservableCollection` all changes to the collection will trigger an update of the UI.

Then I am filling the `Printers` collection in OnRequestSucceeded (without creating a new ObservableCollection). This way you should be able to see the printers as expected.

Comment: Old question and old answer but thank you for the answer anyway. If I remember correctly then I did solve this issue one way or another. I doubt I could figure out what I did in any reasonable amount of time though, I haven't touched the code or the language in 2 years. I'll just give you the benefit of the doubt that this would fix the problem I was having at the time. Thanks again :)